# EXCEL solver, VBA calls unwanted function before launching the solver

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code that should calculate the Fair Values of sevaral different financial securities. The securities come from different issuers, so they are grouped by country and then evaluated.

In order to do so, I need to fit 6 parameters for each group/country, unfortunately these parameters aren't fixed, but they will change every day. I need to recalculated them every time I run my model, so I wrote a subroutine to optimize this problem with the Solver.

So far it works most of the time, but sometimes before lunching the solver the vba code steps into other function of the same spreadsheet and changes the starting values ( read as previous day parameters) of my problem.
These function are not mentioned in the Solver subroutine, they are not even in the same module or sheet.

Any idea of why this is happening? Any Idea of how to prevent VBA stepping inside unwanted function?

here is my Solver code

```
Sub NSCoeff()
Dim current_wb As String
current_wb = ThisWorkbook.Name


Workbooks(current_wb).Sheets("Nelson_Siegel").Calculate
Workbooks(current_wb).Sheets("Nelson_Siegel").Activate
SolverReset
SolverOptions Precision:=0.01, Convergence:=0.1, AssumeNonNeg:=False
SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.001"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$S$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0.001"
SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverOk SetCell:="$N$9", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$N$4:$S$4", _
    Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve userFinish:=True

End Sub
```

Immediately after the last line the code steps into this function

```
Function Discount_Quartic(a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, t As Double) As Double
Dim dr, r As Double
Application.Volatile

r = Worksheets("ImpBond").Cells(4, 26).Value
dr = Worksheets("ImpBond").Cells(4, 27).Value
Discount_Quartic = a * Exp(-r * t) + b * Exp(-r * t * dr) + c * Exp(-r * t * dr ^ 2) + d * Exp(-r * t * dr ^ 3) + (1 - a - b - c - d) * Exp(-r * dr ^ 4 * t)
End Function
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on this:

```
Application.Volatile
```

This method tells the application that the function is `Volatile`. In other words, *every time something changes into the spreadsheet, the function must be recalculated.*

Hence:

- You modify the spreadsheet through your sub `NSCoeff`;
- The `Application` sees what was `Volatile` and recalculates everything it was so. In your case, `Discount_Quartic`. Voilà voilà

Find more about the `Application.Volatile` method [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

And as for *Any Idea of how to prevent VBA stepping inside unwanted function?*, you have two solutions (probably more, but these are the ones coming to my mind now):

- Remove the `Application.Volatile` from the Function. This will, though, not prompt the recalculation of the function anymore (unless you don't explicitly recalculate it).
- Doing a small trick that I will show you with a simple example:

  ```
  Dim dontCall As Boolean '<-- default: False
  Sub dontCallTheFunction()
      Range("A1") = 1 '<-- recalculation prompted, we will get into the function
      dontCall= True'<-- we don't want the function to be recalculated
  End Sub
  Function myFunction()
      Application.Volatile
      If dontCall= False Then
           myFunction = 3
      Else
          dontCall = False '<-- reset the value to False, so next time we'll calculate it normally
      End If
  End Function
  ```

Comment: I've tried to remove the `application.volatile` part by coping my relevant worksheets into a new spreadsheet and then running the Solver again,

Unfortunately it's still not working, if I look through the code the solver doesn't steps into anything unwanted, but the target cell value starts from an higher value that the one that is displayed at the beginning.

i.e. target cell before the solver 59.67
solver starts 
Trial Solution 1 objective cell 2000

Any clue?

Comment: I didn't get something: the function is calculated _after_ or _before_ the execution of your Solver sub? P.s. I didn't understand properly what you did to remove the Application.Volatile, can't you just comment that line of code and uncomment it back after testing?

Comment: Since the problem is not linear and the solver takes long time to go through all the groups. I saved the parameters I've calculated few days ago (before everything was working fine even with the `application volatile`).
The model should read yesterday parameters, load them into the Solver Variable cells (the objective cell should be close enought to the optimal value) and only at this poin the solver should start finding the optimal. Right now is doing the opposite, it loads the old parameters, it lowers the objective cell but when start solving the problem the Objcell is much higher

Comment: Is your problem anyhow related with the fact that the code is _after_ stepping into the function? Please provide a reproducible example (input and code), or I think it's impossible to help you.

Comment: the problem is that the solver starts from an objective cell value higher than those displayed on the spreadsheet.
Right now I'm running only the sub NSCoeff(), I'm manually putting the old parameters into the spreadsheet, then I launch the NSCoeff but it's not working

Comment: I'm sorry but it's impossible for us to debug from here if you don't provide more info. Please give us some values to put into a spreadsheet, a macro to run and the difference between what you expect and what you actually have.

Comment: I don't know which part of the code could be relevant since the model is kind of complex and it consist of several different evaluation model. The application.volatile function are part of the old evaluation model which I would like to keep in the spreadsheet. The only sub I'm running now is the NSCoeff. Thanks anyway Matteo

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters for Solver are meant to be static values based on yesterday's data then you should make a static copy of the values for using with Solver. I suspect that your parameters are the results of calculations which include dates, etc for discounting (and rates, coupons). So when you open the workbook these calcs get updated (your function above was marked as volatile as explained by @ Matteo NNZ) and so Solver starts using the new values.

From your code, Solver is trying to minimise cell N9 by changing cells N4:S4 but keeping both N4 and S4 >= 0.001.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm doing it, there's a worksheet which keeps the old parameters, the macro reads those values and put them in the range N4:S4 (N4 and S4 are used in the denominator so they need to be positive).
After that the values are set in the variable cell the solver should try to minimize the error term, but instead of starting from the old value it starts from some other value, whic actually increase the error and makes the code much slower.

Comment: I'm not sure that solver ever looks at the old starting value.[This site](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-help) is probably where you should be looking.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem of you and found your ask trying to answer mine. I agreed with ChipsLetten then I took a look on my spreadsheet and discovery that I have cells with the function.
So, check if your spreadsheet isn't using the **Discount_Quadratic** in some cells

> (like cell A1 with the formula "=Discount_Quadratic(a,b,c,d,t)")

If you have this function in cells of your spreadsheet, Excel will run this function equal to no cells with this function there is. So, when Excel update the formulas of all the spreadsheet, at any time your code will be interrupted by this update and running the code inside this function, even without you really had called it.